# Are there any HTPC-optimized web browsers?

Tags: browser, htpc

Features that I would ideally include in "HTPC-optimized":

1. Full-screen.
2. Navigable using a remote or the keyboard arrows.
3. Legible at couch distances.

Or, to put it another way, imagine the design requirements for Hulu Desktop or XBMC or WMC, applied to a web browser.

Opera on a Wii meets most of these criteria but not being HD wastes a lot of potential.

If a single solution doesn't exist, is there some combination of Firefox add-ons that will get me there?

Answer (score 3):

Several browsers, like IE, FF, and Opera (I think), support fullscreen mode, and my bet is that at least Firefox supports remote navigation (there's probably at minimum an about:config tweak like [this one](http://www.crunchgear.com/2009/06/30/be-still-my-heart-multi-touch-tab-switching-in-firefox/) to turn it on).

As for being legible, that's not a question of the browser, but the page itself. To make something legible on a big screen from far away, just increase the page zoom (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+scroll wheel in Firefox on Windows, I believe).

Answer (score 3):

Kylo is a new HTPC optimized browser
http://www.kylo.tv/

Comment: another vote for Kylo - it's exactly what you are asking for

Answer (score 0):

I think Opera has all these.

Answer (score 0):

[Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) with [vimium](http://vimium.github.com/) plugin will do.